# "then" used after "but"

Tags: meaning, idioms, dictionaries

> **THEN** *adv*
>
> 4. **Used after *but*** to qualify or balance a preceding statement
>
> **Idiom**: then again
>
> https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=then

Wiktionary has an entry for *but then again* as an "Alternative form of *then again*"

I do not understand what grammatical information the entry is trying to convey: *but then* is not an idiom as *then again* is, but still the definition says *"used after **but**"*.

Comment: [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/but+then+again#:~:text=4.,night%20of%20a%20new%20play.), which should be cited, gives an example: << **then** 4. Used after _but_ to qualify or balance a preceding statement: _The star was nervous, but then who isn't on the first night of a new play[?]_ I consider it a common expression in non-ultra-formal registers. There are plenty of relevant examples for "but then who" in a Google search.  It's not transparent. So I'd say it's an idiom. _One really needs to have evidence to challenge a statement from a respected authority._ Especially when most ...

Comment: dictionaries are in agreement. // As for 'but then again', there are some contexts where the emphasised contrastive is better stylistically. The concessive exists with and without the 'but'.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider it so. Just because the phrase, “But then...” can be used as a stand alone statement following other declarative statements as a counterpoint to those statements. Usually, it is used as an abbreviated statement when the entire statement is implied. For example, “I thought he was smart. But, then...”

Comment: Why are "then again" and "but then" dealt with differently in the entry?

Comment: @GJC - it appears to be used as more of an example of its usage. Not as an exclusive definition. For example, the phrase used in the link you provided, “From another standpoint; on the other hand: I need a vacation. Then again, so do my coworkers.“ can be said as, “From another standpoint; on the other hand: I need a vacation. *But then,* so do my coworkers.“

Comment: Wiktionary has an entry for _but then again_ as an "Alternative form of **then again**"